# iOS how to retrieve URL from sqlite3 databse and send it to webview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite

If someone would like to see, here is my project I'm basing on tutorial and just learning: http://www12.zippyshare.com/v/93404532/file.html
Really sorry that folder naming and everything is such mess.

My current goal is to retrieve URL from sqlite database which is saved in varchar and send this URL to my viewController `- (void)viewDidLoad` like that

```
 [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

My db managing and querying code is in dbManager.m file and it looks like this:

```
//blablabla code code code
while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        HelloWorld *MyString = [[HelloWorld alloc]init];
        MyString.textId = sqlite3_column_int(sqlStatement, 0);
        MyString.helloWorld = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,1)];

        [textArray addObject:MyString];
    }
```

Soooo... how do i do this and then send the URL to webview in viecontroller?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
//Add property in HelloWorld.h

    @property (nonatomic, assign) NSURL *url;

    while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                HelloWorld *MyString = [[HelloWorld alloc]init];
                MyString.textId = sqlite3_column_int(sqlStatement, 0);
                MyString.helloWorld = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,2)];
                NSString *aStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,2)];
                MyString.url = [NSURL URLWithString:aStr];

                [textArray addObject:MyString];
            }


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.webView loadRequest:self.url];
}
```

Comment: In my ViewController.m on
     [self.webView loadRequest:self.url];
it says 'Property URL not found on object of type kcbVievController *'
My url property is in HelloWorld.h ofcourse.
Do you know where should I add my property url?

Comment: Do you have create any member variable in kcbVievController for HelloWorld? if yes than user that object .url

Comment: You can do like this  HelloWorld *aText = (HelloWorld *) [self._strings objectAtIndex: 0];
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:aText.url]];

Comment: Sir, you are awesome. It works!
When i will get 15 rep i will upovte all your posts :>.
THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is this

```
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url value"]]];
```

and the url value can be passed via so many methods.

the one i will use is by define the DB manager class as singleton and use a custom method to return your query response with the return type set to string

so the output of query you will get as

```
NSString *url = [[DBManager sharedinstance] valueForQuery];
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
```

and  the method in DBManager will look as

```
-(NSString*)valueForQuery
{
      //blah blah blah
     return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,1)];
}
```

Comment: Really thanks and it looks awesome, but I have no idea how to use that sharedinstance. Any quick tip?:P